# Adding CSS class to web grid column item conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, encoding

Is it possible to conditionally set a CSS class or encode a string to html for a certain web grid column? I was able to append span tags to the item using format: in the column, but now I need to add a class to the span tags based on a helper function in razor view or a bool expression from the controller/model. **I do not want to do this with JS, C# should suffice**.

Here is what I tried in view model:

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
 headerStyle:"reviewGridHeader",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    ...[other columns]...
    grid.Column(columnName: "FeedBack", format: @<span>@CheckFeedBack(item.FeedBack)</span>)
))
```

Helper function in view model (splits and compares string):

```
    static string CheckFeedBack(string item) {
        String[] feedbacks = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(item, "of");

        //if feedback complete
        if((Convert.ToInt32(feedbacks[0]) == (Convert.ToInt32(feedbacks[1]))))
        {
            string newFeedback = @"<span class=""feedBackComplete"">"+ item +"</span>";
            string encodedFeedback = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(newFeedback);

            return encodedFeedback;
        }
        return item;
    }
```

And here is the presentation, which conditionally works when feedback complete:

[image: feedback column]

**Update:** After guidance from Zach with returning a MvcHtmlString, I had some problems being able to use this helper method above in a WebGrid Column. Below shows the correct syntax:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "FeedBack", format: (item) => CheckFeedBack(item.FeedBack), style: "webGridAlignment")
```

Comment: try to use MvcHtmlString.Create

Comment: your doppelganger got best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return the html not a string... for that case you can use MvcHtmlString and just raw in the view

```
static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString CheckFeedBack(string item) {
        String[] feedbacks = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(item, "of");

        //if feedback complete
        if((Convert.ToInt32(feedbacks[0]) == (Convert.ToInt32(feedbacks[1]))))
        {
            string newFeedback = @"<span class=""feedBackComplete"">"+ item +"</span>";

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(newFeedback);
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(item);
    }
```

Comment: So this did convert the string to html format, but it is still showing up as raw inner text through the Webgrid. As you can see from my grid view, I already have a span in: format: @<span>@CheckFeedBack(..). Could this be causing the problem? And is it possible to have just the helper method in the format property?

For clarity, I want the spans to render as html elements, not to be just encoded.

Comment: sorry, you don't need encode anything when use MvcHtmlString, check out the code, I fix it, so in the view just call the helper without the span, should works fine, and test it out of the grid
`grid.Column(columnName: "FeedBack", format: @CheckFeedBack(item.FeedBack) )`

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to use the helper function in the "format: " property: "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context;" I've tried @CheckFeedBack(@data.FeedBack, item.FeedBack, item: @item.FeedBack) etc... My WebGrid data source is called "data", which is from ViewBag.